# set /p But wait for only one key press without needing to press enter

Tags: batch-file

So I am making a game in batch which in the movement controls are WASD.
I used -
set /p input=
and if %input% is D the player goes right.
But every time I type a letter (W,A,S,D) I have to then press enter.
How can I make it so I don't need to press enter and the %input% is set whenever any key is pressed.
I know there is a way to do this, I remember making a simular project which had it. But it was so long ago I forgot how to do it.

I can't find a solution online because well it's kinda hard describing what I'm looking for.

Comment: Use the `choice` command. `choice /?` tells you about its options.

Comment: Choice by itself is a blocking form of input, which is fine for games where how long the user takes to enter input is irrelevant, however, if you're making any sort of arcade game IE snake / tetris etc where there is a time pressure, you will need to implement non blocking input. Choice and / or Xcopy can both be used to do this, With Xcopy giving you access to more keys. If that's what your after, I have an example script at `https://pastebin.com/Ws5aKkzS`